# Use Java Bean properties instead of fields in jObjectFormatter

Tags: java, jobjectformatter

How can I configure jObjectFormatter to use bean property accessor methods (`get*`, `is*`) instead of accessing the object's fields directly? i.e., the `toString` of the following class:

```
public class Test {
    private String test = "foo";

    private String getTest() {
        return test+"bar";
    }

    @Formatted
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ObjectFormatter.format(this);
    }
}
```

should return "foobar", but it returns "foo".

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible yet. See https://github.com/dtanzer/jobjectformatter/issues/8 for details.